# Change Safari User Agents Persistently

Tags: safari, mojave

Is it possible to change the user agent so that it doesn't change. Currently to change the user agent I go to Develop > User Agent > Other, and then I enter in a custom user agent. However I have to do this on every page I visit. Is there a method to make the user agent persistent?

I have tried the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148323/make-custom-user-agent-change-permanent), but according to panopticlick.eff.org it only uses the default user agent. According to [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327087/macos-mojave-developer-beta-safari-user-agent-change-not-persistent), this is a bug in MacOS Mojave.

Computer Details: Late 2014 Mac Mini running macOS Mojave (v.10.14.5)